# C++ Adding to a vector based on user input

Tags: c++, vector, reference, cin

So I am attempting to input data into an `std::vector`, however I am specifically attempting to assign the data that the user puts in `y` to the `y`th position in the vector.

For example, if the user inputs 1,3, it will put the value 1 into the 3rd position in the vector.

For some reason, I can't seem to get past this error, any suggestions?

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

int main()
{
    vector<int> poly1(100);
    vector<int> poly2(100);
    int x;
    int y;

    int choice;

    std::cout << "What do you wish to do?" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "1. Add two polynomials" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "2. Multiply two polynomials" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "3. Evaluate one polynomial at a given value" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "4. Find Coefficent for a given polynomial and given exponent" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "5. Find the leading exponent for a given polynomial" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "6. Exit "<< std::endl;

    std::cin >> choice;

    if (choice < 1 || choice > 6)
    {
        do
        {
            std::cout << "Invalid entry: please reenter choice" << std::endl;
            std::cin >> choice;

        } while (choice < 1 || choice > 6);
    }

    if (choice == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Please input the first polynomial in the form of: (non-zero coefficient, exponent) pairs" << std::endl;
        std::cin >> x >> y;

        poly1.at[y] = x;
        std::cout << "done" << std::endl;

        system("pause");
    }
    if (choice == 2)
    if (choice == 3)
    if (choice == 4)
    if (choice == 5)
    if (choice == 6)

    system("pause");   
}
```

Comment: `poly1` is an empty vector. `poly1.at[x]` will throw an exception for any value of `x`.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik So i initialized the vector to size 100, however I am still getting an error.

Comment: Make it `poly1[y]` or `poly1.at(y)`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Thank you so much!

Comment: Try `if (y >= poly1.size()) poly1.resize(y + 1)` before `poly1[y] = x` (or `poly1.at(y) = x`).    That will resize the vector before accessing its element.    (It also means that the array will grow based on the largest value of `y` you enter, and will never shrink, which will let your code work, but consume a lot of memory if you give large values of `y`)